# How to change Views in MVC from API controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a mvc application and I want to know how to change views (cshtml pages) from API Controller not mvc controller. It is because of the cshtml and application communicate through ajax services.

Please reply me as soon as possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant change cshtml from api controller, they just return a serialized object. You will need parse this object inside your ajax script and use jquery/javascript to change your cshtml

Comment: Alright thanks. I could not find anything to help my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The API controller is designed to be for things like web services, or for writing the server side backend for a front end rendering framework like Angular JS.

You can do what you want, but you'd have to return something like JSON from your API controller and transform it with Angular JS.

Secondly, you can do AJAX in a normal MVC Controller, just follow a guide like this one, [Guide](http://eliot-jones.com/2014/09/mvc-ajax)

I generally build my MVC applications as Hybrids.  I mix traditional MVC with Angular JS so that all my pages load via normal get requests on normal urls, but do ajax postbacks with angular that way I don't have to worry about SEO or using something like prerender.io...

All of my forms, like contact us, login, etc etc are all hooked by angular controllers and all do ajax postbacks, very fast too.

Update To Comment:

If you want to redirect in angular based on the response of the web api result.. You could do something like this,

```
public object TheMethod(...)
{
    var theJson = new 
    {
        type = "Redirect",
        data = new 
        {
           url = "/submitted",
           form = new 
           {
               firstName = "Bob",
               lastName = "Smith"
           }            
        }
    };
    return theJson;
}
```

Then in your angular response, check the type, and if it's redirect, do a window.location = result.data.url;

Comment: I use the angular js as well. My problem is I send data through ajax service in angular js control. If the ajax service is successful, I need to move to another page.. How to do that?